# How do I know what hardware is supported by Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I am planning to buy a new desktop for myself. I am planning on running Ubuntu on it. How can I be sure that what I am planning to buy ( cpu , graphics card, memory, mainboard ) will work happily with Ubuntu? ( like having drivers, giving full performance etc.. )

Is there any kind of list that I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System76](https://www.system76.com/) sells laptops and desktops with Ubuntu preloaded.  However, they are expensive.  So, you can cheat.  Go into the models they offer and they will tell you what hardware is in them.  Put that specific hardware on your short-list.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxquestions.org/hcl/ is probably a good source.
However that is a community page, so it's only as good as the contributions.

CPU and Motherboards are definitely going to work for at least the basic functions. The issues you may have would be with integrated NICs and Sound Cards, though in general Linux has a very broad range of support.

A good way to find out is to google the chipset itself for the motherboard or NIC and read up on the experiences that people have had with that particular chipset.

Memory won't have much to do with Linux, more to do with the motherboard itself, so as long as the Memory is on the Motherboards Qualified Vendors List, you shouldn't have any issues there.

For graphics cards, I would go with Nvidia as their Linux support is generally better than ATIs, however ATI is catching up pretty fast still.

Answer (score 1):

When the fear of hardware incompatibilities puts you off buying a new computer be sure to run your intended purchase through Canonical’s ‘Ubuntu Certification’ website.To gain ‘Ubuntu Certified’ status hardware is tested by Canonical engineers.‘Ubuntu Ready’ applies to hardware self-tested by OEMs using Canonical’s certification test suite with results submitted to Canonical for validation.If you don’t find your device listed don’t assume that it isn’t compatible. Not every device manufacturer has submitted their hardware for testing. Check out the community-reviewed compatibility pages on the Ubuntu Wiki.

Head over to [webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/](http://webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/) to check out the current tally of compatible hardware  and search on any prospective machines you’re considering buying.